# Three.js - How to animate a 3D model using data from pose estimation

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, rotation, mediapipe

I'm trying to use pose estimation coordinates to animate a rigged model in three.js The pose estimation tech I'm using provides real time x,y,z coordinates from a person in a video feed and I'm trying to use those to move the 3D model accordingly.  I used the code below (some of which I found in an answer to a related question) as a starting point...

```js
let camera, scene, renderer, clock, rightArm;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
  camera.position.set(2, 2, -2);

  clock = new THREE.Clock();

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);

  const light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xbbbbff, 0x444422);
  light.position.set(0, 1, 0);
  scene.add(light);

  // model
  const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
  loader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/models/gltf/Soldier.glb', function(gltf) {

    const model = gltf.scene;

    rightArm = model.getObjectByName('mixamorigRightArm');

    scene.add(model);

  });

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

  const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.target.set(0, 1, 0);
  controls.update();

}

function onWindowResize() {

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

//This was my attempt at deriving the rotation from two vector3's and applying it to the model
//storedresults is simply an array where I store the pose estimation data for a given position
//getPosition is just a helper function for getting the vector three for a specific position
function setRightArmRotation() {
  if (rightArm) {
    if (storedresults === undefined || storedresults.length == 0) {
      return;
    } else {
      if (vectorarray.length < 2) {
        vectorarray.push(getPosition(12));
      } else {
        vectorarray.pop();
        vectorarray.push(getPosition(12));
        var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
        quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(vectorarray[0], vectorarray[1]);
        var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
        matrix.makeRotationFromQuaternion(quaternion);
        rightArm.applyMatrix4(matrix);
      }
    }
  }
}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  const t = clock.getElapsedTime();

  if (rightArm) {

    rightArm.rotation.z += Math.sin(t) * 0.005;
    //setRightArmRotation()

  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.125.2/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.125.2/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.125.2/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

I also referred to this answer on finding rotations from two vectors but I haven't been successful in implementing it to achieve the desired results...
[How to find rotation matrix between two vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199173/how-to-find-rotation-matrix-between-two-vectors-in-three-js)

I can get the Vector3 from the pose estimation tech easily, and I understand how most of what is in the jsfiddle works but I can't seem to put it all together to get the desired result of having my 3D model 'mirror' the movement of what is in my video using the pose estimation coords.  I pretty much can just get the model to 'thrash around'.

As I understand it I need to manipulate the rotations of the bones to achieve the desired results, and to do that I need to compute those rotations using two vectors, but again after much research and trial and error I just can't seem to put it all together.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather big answer, so I'll split this down in to smaller parts.

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess you're using posenet (tensorflow library).

I've had this issue before, and it is very complicated to come up with a solution, but here's what worked for me.

First, using posenet, match each bone in the mesh, to a bone in the keypoints array.

Then I created a Skeleton class that recreated a skeleton in primitive terms, each bone had a seperate class, for instance elbow joint etc.. These all had max hyperextension and retraction values, it took a series of Vector3 values that basically showed the min and max xyz rotation values (similar to the range of movement we have) and converted this from degrees to radians.

from there, I applied all the rotations to each bone, the rotations were nowhere near perfect though, as the arms would often rotate inside the body. To combat this, I created a bounding box round each bone (to the outer mesh) and did collision detection on each part until the bone no longer collided with another part of the mesh, I had a tolerance score for each body part (i.e allow arms to be crossed or legs)

from there I had a "somewhat" good estimate which was applied to a 3d mesh.

I've got some of the original stuff on github if you'd like to see an example:
https://github.com/hudson1998x/2D-To-3D-Pose-Estimation/

Comment: Nice! It would be cool to see this in action, but I couldn't get the project running locally. It complained about peer dependencies during installation, and had some other issues once I got past that. I'm using blazepose in my project, which provides 3D positions, so I thought it would be as simple as getting the direction vector between two joints and applying rotation to the bones, but there's something I'm missing. Anyway, thanks for sharing your insights!

Comment: The work on the repo was halted due to not enough time. But yeah I think it matches the same concept of what you have 