# How to add .fbx animataion from Mixamo in gltf (glb) model?

Tags: three.js, gltf, mixamo

I have a glb model in my code.

I have downloded animations from https://www.mixamo.com/#/?page=1&type=Motion%2CMotionPack

Please help to add these  fbx animations on glb model in Three.js

Comment: if the model the animation was made for has diffrent bones then your glb there is no way this will work

Comment: Hi @cubesareneat , model has skeleton , wirefire .Could you please suggest how could I make my model walk by the means of three.js. It will be a great help :)                             model has Stats:1 draw calls,0 animations,1 materials,7014 vertices,11776 triangles

Comment: you are going to want to use some sort of animation software like blender. doing it in three is not impossible, but it might as well be for how difficult it would be . a video on how to animate https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imbIsNAvUpM&ab_channel=Polyfjord or you can search mixamo for a model that works with their animations.

Comment: i dont know if mixamo provides .blend files if you find .blend files you can edit the model in blender, as long as you leave the rigging alone you can still use the animations (for the most part) this person makes great .blend models that i have used quaternius.com

Comment: Thanks @cubesareneat,  there is one example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69679303/three-js-how-to-animate-a-3d-model-using-data-from-pose-estimation .in this they have moved 1 hand of the model,I also want to use this kind of fuctionality to move the body parts of the glb model.Please suggest how it could be achieved

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bdmrg4oc/1/

Comment: @cubesareneat Thank you so much I could make the model legs move but now the problem is that the legs are rotating 360 degree.  https://jsfiddle.net/bdmrg4oc/1/ good one.                                                                                                             
    LeftUpLeg = modelNeil.getObjectByName('LeftUpLeg');
    RightUpLeg = modelNeil.getObjectByName('RightUpLeg');   and at last in animate function if ( LeftUpLeg ) {
 LeftUpLeg.rotation.x += Math.sin( t ) * 0.005;
 
 }